# Why code inside "script" is not working in html?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, typescript

I am doing a really simple task. I am adding some javascript code in html of a simple web project created on Visual studio 2019. But it is not running the code inside a script tag and also not giving any error. I know it's gonna be really small mistake that i am unable to figure out right now. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Code</h1>
    <button type="button"
            onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
        Click me to display Date and Time.
    </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = "John Doe";  // String written inside quotes
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    </script>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

After running a code, code within button tag is working fine but script isn't working. Sorry for a really stupid question. I will highly appreciate your help

Comment: Try put that two `<p>` before `script`

Comment: Browsers usually assume the worst case scenario and load scripts synchronously,  during HTML parsing. So your reference elements should come before your script.

Comment: @FaizanKamal glad to help, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script tag is added before `<p id="demo1"></p>` which you reference in your script. So when the script runs there is no such tag and "John Doe" can't be added to it. Fixed:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JS Code</h1>
    <button type="button"
            onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
        Click me to display Date and Time.
    </button>

    

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = "John Doe";  // String written inside quotes
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow I am such an idiot. Thanks mate. Btw I have another question. Why don't self-closing script is not working in visual studio?

Comment: @FaizanKamal `<script>` can't be self closed